# Move UIImage across screen using core animation

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, core-animation, caanimation

DO NOT POST ANSWERS ABOUT UIVIEW ANIMATIONS I understand UIView, I am learning core-animation. Im trying to get an image to move 50 units to the right but I am having many issues. First when the animation is called the image jumps to a new location, runs, then jumps back to the original location. I want it to simply move 50 units to the right, stop, move again if the button is pressed. I have spent a lot of time researching and I can't seem to find the problem. My Code:

```
-(IBAction)preform:(id)sender{

CGPoint point = CGPointMake(imView.frame.origin.x, imView.frame.origin.y);
imView.layer.position = point;

CABasicAnimation *anim = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position.x"];
anim.fromValue  = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:point];
anim.toValue    = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(point.x + 50, point.y)];
anim.duration   = 1.5f;
anim.repeatCount =1;
anim.removedOnCompletion = YES;
anim.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn];
[imView.layer  addAnimation:anim forKey:@"position.x"];
imView.layer.position = point;

}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I see several problems in your code.

First, you're grabbing the frame origin like this:

```
CGPoint point = CGPointMake(imView.frame.origin.x, imView.frame.origin.y);
```

Although it's not really a problem, you could simply do this:

```
CGPoint point = imView.frame.origin;
```

The problem is that you're setting the layer's `position` to its frame's origin.  But by default, the position controls the **center** of the view, and the frame's origin is its upper-left corner.  You probably want to just pick up the layer's position in the first place:

```
CGPoint point = imView.layer.position; // equivalent to imView.center
```

Second, you're using the `position.x` key path, which wants a `CGFloat` value, but you're providing a `CGPoint` value.  This doesn't appear to cause a problem in the iOS 6.1 simulator, but it's probably a bad idea to assume it will always work.

Third, you need to understand that an animation does **not** change the properties of your layer!  Each of the layers you normally manipulate (technically called a *model* layer) has an associated *presentation* layer.  The presentation layer's properties control what is on the screen.  When you change a model layer's property, Core Animation usually sets up an animation (from the old value to the new value) on the presentation layer automatically.  This is called an implicit animation.  A `UIView` suppresses implicit animations on its layer.

When the animation on the presentation layer ends and is removed, the presentation layer's properties revert to its model layer's values.  So to make the change permanent, you need to update the model layer's properties.  Generally it's best to update the model layer's properties *first*, then add the animation, so that your explicit animation overwrites the implicit animation (if one was created).

As it happens, although you can animate `position.x`, you need to set `position` on the `model` layer to make it stick.  I tested this to work:

```
- (IBAction)perform:(id)sender {
    CGPoint point0 = imView.layer.position;
    CGPoint point1 = { point0.x + 50, point0.y };

    CABasicAnimation *anim = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position.x"];
    anim.fromValue    = @(point0.x);
    anim.toValue  = @(point1.x);
    anim.duration   = 1.5f;
    anim.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn];

    // First we update the model layer's property.
    imView.layer.position = point1;

    // Now we attach the animation.
    [imView.layer  addAnimation:anim forKey:@"position.x"];
}
```

(Note that I called my method `perform:`.  The method in the original post seems to be misspelled.)

If you want to really understand Core Animation, I highly recommend watching the [Core Animation Essentials video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/?id=421) from WWDC 2011.  It's an hour long and contains a ton of useful information.

Comment: Thanks ill watch the video!

Comment: @robmayoff this doesn't work on swift. And I don't know why. I repeated code on swift, but have problem with the return to the start position. I don't understand. Code from this article doesn't work too(same issue): http://www.objc.io/issue-12/animations-explained.html#fnref3   But, works normal with opacity. Updating the model layer's opacity property after animation stop, will left opacity with the value you had set.

Comment: Please post your own question and include your Swift code.

Answer (score 1):

This is what you should need to get it working. The position on the layer is already set so you can use that as the `fromValue` and just modify it to get the `toValue`. The other important step is to set the layers position to be `endPos` so that when the animation finishes, the image view will stay at the correct position.

```
-(IBAction)preform:(id)sender
{
    CGPoint startPos = imView.layer.position;
    CGPoint endPos = CGPointMake(point.x + 50, point.y);

    CABasicAnimation *anim = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position.x"];
    anim.fromValue  = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:startPos];
    anim.toValue    = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:endPos];
    anim.duration   = 1.5f;
    anim.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn];

    [imView.layer addAnimation:anim forKey:@"position.x"];
    imView.layer.position = endPos;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

jumping back is caused by the fact that you remove animation on completion

```
anim.removeOnCompletion = NO;
```

EDIT #3: just copied and tried your code here is the fix for all of your issues, pretty much self explanatory :

```
CGPoint point = imView.center;
CABasicAnimation *anim = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position.x"];
anim.fromValue  = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:point.x];
anim.toValue    = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:point.x+50.0];//[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(point.x + 50, point.y)];
anim.duration   = 1.5f;
anim.repeatCount =1;
anim.removedOnCompletion = NO;
anim.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn];
anim.fillMode=kCAFillModeForwards;
[imView.layer  addAnimation:anim forKey:@"position.x"];
[sender.layer  addAnimation:anim forKey:@"position.x"];
sender.layer.position=CGPointMake(point.x+50.0,sender.layer.position.y);
```

That fact that it jumps back even though removedOnCompletion is set to no is a head scratcher. Still playing around with it.

Comment: Setting `removeOnCompletion` to `NO` is almost never the right answer.  If you think it is the answer, you should watch the [Core Animation Essentials video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/?id=421) from WWDC 2011.

Comment: Yup. That changes absolutely nothing.

Comment: last thin missing is anim.fillMode=kCAFillModeForwards;

Comment: Seriously, watch the video.  The solution you're suggesting doesn't update the model layer.  If Tanner wants to animate, say, a button, the button will stop working because hit testing is performed on the model layer, not the presentation layer.